# Snakemake - delete all non-output files produced by a workflow

Tags: snakemake

I have a workflow that produces tons of files, most of them are not the output of any rule (they are intermediate results). I'd like to have the option of deleting everything that is not the output of any rule **after** the workflow is complete. This would be useful for archiving.
Right now the only way I found to do that is to define all outputs of all rules as protected, and then run `snakemake --delete-all-output`. Two questions:
1. Is this the way to go, or is there a better solution?
2. Is there a way to automatically define all outputs as protected, or do I have to go through the entire code and wrap all outputs with `protected()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the option [--list-untracked](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html) helps?

```
  --list-untracked, --lu
                        List all files in the working directory that are not
                        used in the workflow. This can be used e.g. for
                        identifying leftover files. Hidden files and
                        directories are ignored.
```

Comment: Yes, this is very useful! One can use something like `snakemake --list-untracked   2>&1 >/dev/null | xargs rm`. This always operates on the current working directory, so take care.

Comment: I think `--list-untracked` operates on the directory specified by `--directory/-d` which, by default, is the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @dariober's suggestion, here's a few ideas:

- It sounds like you know this already, but you could wrap unneeded output in `temp()`, which will cause Snakemake to delete it automatically. You can combine this with `--notemp` for debugging. With `temp()`, deletion will happen progressively, not after the workflow is complete.
- Another option may be to use the `onsuccess` hook defined by snakemake. From the [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html), "The `onsuccess` handler is executed if the workflow finished without error." So, say, if throughout the workflow, you put unneeded file in a `temp/` folder or similar, you could use `shutil.rmtree("temp")` in `onsuccess`, which would delete all your unneeded files only after the workflow finished successfully, as you require. (Note also the similar `onerror`, should you need it.)

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware of these handy features, but they don't really solve my problem here...